# Android Layout complexo utilizando fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragment

Estou com dificuldade para criar um rodapé (footer).  O problema está na posição horizontal do tablet onde tenho dois framelayout e preciso incluir o rodapé ocupando toda parte inferior (abaixo dos framelayout).  Meu código está assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/lado_esquerdo"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/lado_direito"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2" />
```

Alguma sugestão? Algum material que possa consultar? Já tentei incluir dois tipos de layouts, mas não funcionou.

Desde já agradeço pela ajuda.

---

Segue o código:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#95accf" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#95accf" >
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/footer" />
</RelativeLayout>

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
    android:stretchColumns="0">

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/descricao"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="DESCRIÇÃO"
            android:textSize="40dp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/preco"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="TESTES"
            android:textSize="40dp" />
    </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: use RelativeLayout na view pai

Comment: Duanniston, vou testar com RelativeLayout.   Obrigado.

Comment: Duanniston, estou usando o RelativeLayout.  Meu problema agora é a imagem do rodapé, informei a largura do RelaativeLayout com 120dp, no tablet 9'' fica perfeito. Quando executo a aplicação em um tablet menor a imagem sobe, não alinha na parte inferior.  Teria como definir essa largura de forma proporcional ao tamanho do dispositivo?